# Смена фона (у элемента (к примеру, div)) с помощью jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сменить фон у элемента посредством JQuery методом .animate?

Comment: [https://jqueryui.com/animate](https://jqueryui.com/animate) тут даже с примером

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#menu a").hover(function(){
    $("#menu").css("background", "#f00");
},
function(){
    $("#menu").css("background", "#00f");
});
```

Comment: а где метод `animate`?

Comment: немного не в тему: я пользовался этим методом, но у меня был ajax, и после цепочки запросов при возврате на страницу где этот код должен работать - он не работал, я решил несерьезным создавать подобный вопрос, не подскажете как с этим быть?)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="element" style="background-color:#fff; width:100px; height:100px;"></div>

<script>
    $("#element").hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#000"}, 1000);
    });
</script>
```